# Move Mongo Embeded Document into Own Collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, migration, migrate

Can someone point me in the right direction, i have a Collection (Forms) each Form has an embedded document array (Responses). Responses for each form have gotten massive and in hindsight embedding them was a bad idea (mongo documents including embedded have a maximum size limit).

Is there a way i can quickly and easily move all of these embedded Responses into their own collection? is there such a thing like the old SQL select into? I have had a look around in rails console but it is inaccessible with so many embedded documents, so i imagine it'll have to be a complex find and insert query in the mongo console? (just guessing there)

My Model is fixed but this migration (and the mongo docs) are stumping me.

TIA
Dougle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So here's a start... This is in the mongo shell

```
db.questions.insert({name:"jwo", responses:[{question:"your name?", answer:"yomamma"}, {question:"your name?", answer:"pappa"}]});
```

This created a document json structure like so:

```
> db.questions.findOne();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4d877e89b75dc42c4709278d"),
    "name" : "jwo",
    "responses" : [
        {
            "question" : "your name?",
            "answer" : "yomamma"
        },
        {
            "question" : "your name?",
            "answer" : "pappa"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now loop through the responses, and set their question_id with the questions' _id, and then insert it into the new responses collection

```
> for(i=0; i<question.responses.length; ++i){
... question.responses[i].question_id = question._id;   
... db.responses.insert(question.responses[i]);                                                                      
... }

> db.responses.findOne();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4d878059b75dc42c4709278e"),
    "question" : "your name?",
    "answer" : "yomamma",
    "question_id" : ObjectId("4d877e89b75dc42c4709278d")
}
```

You'll want to change the db.questions.findOne to find all of them and loop over. If this does take a while, you may need to switch to a map-reduce function.

Comment: This worked a treat thanks, you're right it did take a while :oD

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code we ended up with, based off Jesse Wolgamott's answer.

```
var count = 0;
db.transactions.find().sort({_id: 1}).forEach(function(t){
  if(count % 10000 == 0)
    print(""+t._id+" "+count);

  count += 1;

  for(i=0; i<t.inputs.length; ++i){
    t.inputs[i].transaction_id = t._id;
    db.input2s.insert(t.inputs[i]);
  }
});
```